Create a Offline Repository for Linux Mint
In our environment we have handful of Linux Mint 21.3 Machines which are recently deployed that will be used with PAM Solution , Unfortunately Cyber team disallowed access to Linux website to get the patches.
Is there a way to download the repository and i write a small script that will run on weekends and get the new patches from Mint website. And later offline nodes will get the packages and patches from this Repo Server?

Would your admins allow that? Because, if they allow that, then they should also allow you to access the repository URL. From a security point of view, there is no difference between what you are suggesting and allowing access to the repositories directly.

they are ready to provide access from one machine which have no direct connection to these internal servers . Only internal servers (Offline) should contact this Repository server.

I'm by no means an expert, so this is a suggestion, not an answer. Could you set up a mirror, as described here http://littlesvr.ca/grumble/2020/07/12/set-up-your-own-linux-mint-mirror-for-lightning-fast-downloads/ . P.S. Mint are about to change their repository supplier (in Mint 22.0 probably). You can read about that in their April 2024 monthly news https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=4675 .
